Resume mongodb stream from the point where it stopped
I am streaming huge amount of data from mongodb to other service.
For this i am using mongodb stream. But due to some reason if stream stops i want to rerun the job from where it stopped rather than starting it from start.
My question is if i store the last document id where it failed and rerun the stream from that document will this work ? Does streaming mongodb collection preserve same order every time or do i need to add sortBy for this ?
Is mongo _id field good to store in order to resume from last checkpoint ? also i assume i have to sort the stream based on _id for this ?
This is the stream i am using
db
    .collection(PRODUCTS_COLLECTION)
    .aggregate<MongoProduct>([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'prices',
          localField: 'sku',
          foreignField: 'sku',
          as: 'price'
        }
      },
      {
        $project: {
          sku: 1,

        }
      },
      {
        $match: {}
      }
    ])
    .stream();


You could be looking for page-based pagination or cursor-based pagination. But at current status, your question needs more focus and clarity.
